# Substitute string in BASH with Sed (when it has special characters)

Tags: bash, replace, sed

It's a fairly simple question and I'm sure the gurus here can figure it out right away, however I don't seem to be able to make it work (probably some quotes issue.

I want to place all instances of:

```
`which cat`
```

With the following:

```
/bin/cat
```

I am running the following command:

```
for file in $(find . -iname 'PATCH*'); do sed 's/\`which cat\`/\'\/bin\/cat/g' $file; done
```

I believe I have escaped all characters that don't need to be treated as special ones, however it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Please help :)

Comment: I don't know why the single quote comes before `/bin`

Comment: Well spotted. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to iterate over the output of `find` since file names can contain the `$IFS` which would break the loop. Use the `-exec` option of `find` instead:

```
find -iname 'PATCH*' -exec sed -i 's#`which cat`#/bin/cat#g' {} \;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you for the suggestion and the information that I can delimit with #s too. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a different sed delimiter.

```
sed 's~`which cat`~/bin/cat~g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '`which cat`' | sed 's~`which cat`~/bin/cat~g'
/bin/cat
```

Comment: Works like a charm with a different delimiter. I wasn't aware of them previously. Many thanks :)